# Processor fan doesn't work until temps are high

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, cpu, fan

First of all, hello to all!
I have noticed that the laptop's processor fan doesn't start working until the temperatures of the cores and CPU reach somewhat high stats (around 50°C, usually a bit higher). When the fan is working, it is spinning with around 2500-2600 RPM (I checked it using Psensor). I'm not sure if this classifies as a problem or just a characteristic, but is there a way that allows the machine to work with temps of around 35-40°C with the fan running constantly at lower RPM? Another odd thing I noticed is there's another fan, and I get the following when I run psensor through Terminal:

`[ERR] lmsensor: Cannot get value of subfeature fan1_input: Can't read.`

I tried installing TLP, but it just seems to aggravate this condition. My OS is Kubuntu 18.04, I have worked with standard Ubuntu, Xubuntu and Ubuntu Mate, the situation is the same with them. I'd be thankful if someone has a solution.

Comment: I dont think that you situation is a problem. 50 celsius is even a normal temperature(considering you are on a laptop). I think that the Fan only start to run at there RPM when you give a good effort to the processor, for avoid it get more hot. I even consider that have the fan always on would not be good for it(more usage= more % of get broken) and because you will get more dirt in the laptop inside pieces(because if you pull out air it will go inside from another part of the machine). Going back to the question, i really dont have idea of how force the fan to being "always on"

Comment: Nothing wrong with 50°C.

Comment: Nice! Yeah, just wanted to make sure it's working properly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It's normal. Maximum safe temperature of CPU is much higher. So there is no reason for fan to start. And it is not a good idea to have fan running constantly.
Links: https://www.techcenturion.com/optimal-temperature-of-cpu-and-gpu

Comment: Wow, what a great article, massive thanks for the link!